# What is the Erase Block Size of my Vaio SSD disk?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, sony-vaio

I have a Vaio VPCZ12X9E/X with a RAID 0 SSD Flash Quad, 128 GB. To install Archlinux I need to know the Erase Block Size (EBS) of the SSD drive.

As the EBS is vendor specific, I tried with some utilities such as Speccy, but the result for the Hard Drive is "Unknown manufacturer".

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an SSD there is a level of indirection between blocks (smallest writable amount) and pages (smallest erasable amount). A given block can be stored almost anywhere on the SSD and moves each time it is written to, both for wear leveling reasons and to avoid erasing and writing to a whole page.

Witting 1k to a SSD does not make it erase a whole page unless there are no free pages. It writes the data to one block then does whatever metadata updates required to make note that logical block X is now stored in physical location Y. Yes this means the old copy of the block could hang around for a long time - until the page it was on gets erased.

In more bare metal flash storage which does not have this level of indirection a parameter like EBS would matter but not for a SSD.